# How to add a table below a figure in \figure environment

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

I want to add a table inside a `\figure` environment so the figure has a table **below** it. I want to do this so I can have a caption that explain the figure and its result in this table.

```
            \begin{figure}[!htbp]
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=90mm]{fig.pdf}
                 \vspace{-5em}

    % This table does not appear
            \begin{table}
        \def\arraystretch{1.3}
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
        {
        \begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.4cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.4cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.4cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.4cm} } 

        \hline
        \vspace{0.12in}
        \shortstack{\textbf{Links}\\ \color{white} } & 
        \shortstack{\textbf{Scenario 1} \\ (Tree)} &
        \shortstack{\textbf{Scenario 2} \\ (Graph)}  &
        \shortstack{\textbf{Scenario 3} \\ (Matrix)}  \\ 
        \hline

        \end{tabular}
        }
        \end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%% End of table %%%%%%%%%%%%  

            \caption{Figure and its result from the experiment}
             \label{fig}
            \end{figure}
```

Comment: You mean how to add a `tabular` not a `table` ?

Comment: I meant table, sorry. I just updated the post

Comment: Can you just add it? Like this `\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=90mm]{X}

    \begin{tabular}[c]{|p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}|}\hline
             A&B\\\hline
             C&D\\\hline
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Figure and its result from the experiment}
 \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`  screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NtIUm.png)

Comment: Ok, I saw first you said `tabular` then updated to `table`. You can't add `table` since it is float inside float (figure is float). It is like adding a figure inside a figure. Latex does not like this. Try this and you get same error `\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \end{figure}
\end{figure}
`

Comment: First, you can put a tabular and \captionof}{table} (caption package} inside a figure.  Since the code inside a figure environment is expanded immediately (except for \protected@write) there is no guarantee that the table won't show up before the figure, especially if it is smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting float in float is not right way to combining image and table as sub-floats in one float  This can be simple done as show MWE below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx}% added for table design
\usepackage{show frame}% for show page layout, in real use it had to be removed
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.7\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{picture}
    \end{subfigure}

    \bigskip% <-- added
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}<-- changed width
        \centering
        \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% <-- added
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}% <-- added
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}% <-- changed
    \hline
\textbf{Links} & \textbf{Scenario 1} & \textbf{Scenario 2} & \textbf{Scenario 3}  \\
      ???      &    (tree)           &    (Graph)          &  (Matrix)            \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
        \caption{table}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Some wonderful words.}
    \label{my label}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mike, meanwhile you receive two answers. Please respond if any of them help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a matter of float in float, i think its a matter of `\centering\arraybackslash` and the other stuf. If I do a simple example with just a normal table it works:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.7\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=90mm]{X}
    \caption{picture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.7\textwidth}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                $A$ & $v_1$ & $\sum_a^b$ \\ \hline
                105 & 452 & tree \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{table}
        \end{table}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{some wonderful words.}
    \label{thisisalabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]
But if i use your table nothing moves... Maybe there is a "easier way" to build the table you want?