# Table below figure, spanning two columns

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

In one of my documents, I am attempting to put have a table inside of a figure environment, and have one caption that refers to both of the above (I am trying to have the table act as a separate panel). I haven't been able to make this work however.

I am going to borrow code from another question that was asked here before, since I think it would do essentially what I want to do. However, if someone knows how to a) have the "combined figure" span two columns (which I think is just a matter of adding a star inside {figure}) and b) have the image and table widths automatically span the width of the two columns, that would be great.

The code that I'm referring to is Zarko's answer here [How to add a table below a figure in \figure environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319708/how-to-add-a-table-below-a-figure-in-figure-environment)

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding a): Use `figure*` instead of `figure`. Regarding b): Replace `\columnwidth` by `\textwidth`

Comment: Perfect - thank you @leandriis. How do I give you a checkmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain a figure that uses the width of both columns in a twocolumn document, use `figure*` instad of `figure`. In order to make the table and image as wide as the textwidth, replace `\columnwidth` by `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.7\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{picture}
    \end{subfigure}

    \bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \hline
\textbf{Links} & \textbf{Scenario 1} & \textbf{Scenario 2} & \textbf{Scenario 3}  \\
      ???      &    (tree)           &    (Graph)          &  (Matrix)            \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
        \caption{table}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Some wonderful words.}
    \label{my label}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]