# Nesting deluxetable and figure in AASTeX

Tags: nesting, aastex

I'm using AASTeX's two-column style and I was trying to 'combine' a figure and table into one fitted inside a single column. However, the figure doesn't display including the "main figure's" caption.

Edited to suffice for MWE as below-mentioned.

```
\documentclass{article} %Suggest on using AASTeX Two-Column
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx} %table design
\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.456\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{My figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    % This figure doesn't appear

    \bigskip% <-- added
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}<-- changed width
        \centering
        \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% <-- added
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{deluxetable}{ccc}
    \centering
    \tablenum{1}
    \tablecolumns{3}
    \tablecaption{Sample Table}
        \tablehead{
        \colhead{1} & \colhead{2} & \colhead{3}}}
        \startdata
        XXX & YYY & ZZZ
        \enddata
    \end{deluxetable}
        \caption{A table} % Doesn't appear
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Words} % Doesn't appear
    \label{my label}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I'm apparently not as good as anyone here but I'm hoping one can guide me on how can I do that. Thanks a lot c:

I'll also 'attach'/include the photo (a big one lol) that I'm trying to add. [Photo](https://prnt.sc/10o35j0)

Reference *(Please kindly check here as I tried to incorporate it with the existing deluxetable. Unfortunately, the figure doesn't show up :c )*: [This One](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319708/how-to-add-a-table-below-a-figure-in-figure-environment)

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Ok did it. It's not a great MWE of mine but I think that 'should' work(?)